# Steam API load the items json

Tags: php, json, steam

Hello guys i started to try use Steam API and i already done login... but i have a big problem to get items. I cant find solution what im doing wrong.

```
$GetClientSteamItemsUrl = " http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/" . $_SESSION['steam_steamid'] . "/inventory/json/730/2";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $GetClientSteamItemsUrl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 3);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
$ArrayInventory = json_decode($output, true);
foreach($ArrayInventory['rgDescriptions'] as $inventory)
{
    echo $inventory;
}
```

On that link is my items that i want to write their name on my page.

Error: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /data/web/virtuals/112855/virtual/www/subdom/ayy/index.php

Can someone help me to select specific part of code?

Comment: first argument of `foreach()` needs to be an array, not a key within the array you are iterating over.

Comment: Anyways im not able to get data

Comment: If you do not need all of the data from the API Response for a particular task, look into extracting the specific portions of data you need from `$ArrayInventory` into its own. I never interacted with the steam api, so I don't know the structure of their data to give a solution post.

Comment: Have you verified that `$ArrayInventory['rgDescriptions']` is an array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$inventory = file_get_contents("http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/".$_SESSION['steamid']."/inventory/json/730/2");
$myarrayInv = json_decode($inventory, true);  
foreach($myarrayInv['rgDescriptions'] as $item) 
{
echo $item['name']; 

}
```

if you want icon_url etc. do $item['icon_url'], hope this helps.

Comment: No thats not the problem. Read the code again and the error message.